# read the excel file from the directory not from the address that you given

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am using html5 and javascript. I want to read the Excel file which is chosen by the user from the directory (using a file dialog) but all I know is to read an excel file by the given path:

```
function readdata(y,x) {
    try {
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        excel.Visible = false;
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");
        //  alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
        //alert(data);
        drawWithexcelValue(data);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is what I have to read the excel file. Can any one help me to read a file by directory, or without giving the path of the file. I would also like to know how to show output from that.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code, it is a bit of a hack and it seems to work with IE7.  However, it will not work with other browsers because they will not show the file path.  Other browsers will also never be able to show the ActiveXObject (Excel).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="divHidden" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px">
  <input type=file id="fileInput">
</div>
<input type=button value="click here to get a file" onclick="readdata(1,1);">

<script language=javascript>

    function readdata(y,x) {

        // Use the <input type='file'...> object to get a filename without showing the object.
        document.all["fileInput"].click();
        var fileName = document.all["fileInput"].value;

        try {
            var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            excel.Visible = false;
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

            var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
            //  var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
            var data;
            for (; excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value.length > 0; x++){
                data[i][0] = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
                data[i][1] = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y+1).Value;
            }
            drawWithexcelValue(data);
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }

        // This will show the data.
        alert(data);

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: brother @psiphi75 i appreciate  you for the code but  the line
dialog = new ActiveXObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog");  
 is not compiling there is something wrong in it.i cant find it thats y i thought i might know it..

Comment: @user2502227 I have updated the answer.  You should be able to copy this to a file and run it directly.

Comment: brother  i  thanks alot for giving me your precious time .your code is reading file which is incredible but it is only reading one column which is name column but it is not reading the value column and one more thing it is showing only one value not the whole file values...it will be very appreciated if you can do some magic with your code..and thanx once again for the code

Comment: @user2502227, you never mentioned that you want to read a whole column of data.  What does the data look like?  Which Cell does the data start in (e.g. "A2", "B3", etc) ?  Are there always the same number of rows?  If yes, how many rows are there?

Comment: there are two column A and B there are some strings in A column  and in B column there are some integer values less than or equal to 100 ... for ex we have values on A1 is cricket and on B1 is 67

      nagendra         50
      rahul         80
      shoaib         90 
      sonu         25
      ankit          56
this will be the ex of values and yes all the files will be the same...

Comment: but the rows will  be untold ,may be sometime it will be 25 or may be next time it will 90.and so on

Comment: @user2502227 Now it gets more complicated. What are you trying to do with "drawWithexcelValue"? What kind of variable should data be (a single value, or an array of column A and B values, or two arrays one with Column A and the other with column B)?

Comment: an array of column A and B , the column A  will contain string type values and column b contains Integer types values which is under 0 to 90 .....thnx a lot @psiphi75 for showing interest in my Q ..i means  a lot for me..thanx

Comment: And DrawWithExcelValue is ment for to read the data from excel file and show the data on speedometer ,,suppose that "somename" and its value is 65 ,,so this function is for retrieving the value  and show value 65 by rotating the niddle  of speedo meter

Comment: if you want full source code of my project than u can ask me for that

Comment: Hi @user2502227, I have updated the code.  However, your mileage may vary, because the original code is quite far away from the code you were expecting.  I have had to make a lot of assumptions, maybe you get the idea and you can fix it.  Yes, the supporting code would help.

Comment: thanx a lot brother ..this mean a lot to me