# Read the excel file from the specific location

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to use this way([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329357/read-the-excel-file-from-the-directory-not-from-the-address-that-you-given))
because I don't want to open new window for file selection. 
I just want to load & read excel file when I click some button.
But this is not work.. help me to load the excel file.

MYCODE:

```
const FILE_NAME = "C:/Users/A/project_list.xlsx";

function LoadSpread(json) {
  jsonData = json;
  workbook.fromJSON(json);

  workbook.setActiveSheet("Revenues (Sales)");
}

function excelExport(fileName) {
  console.log(fileName);

  var excelUrl = fileName;

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("get", excelUrl, true);
  oReq.responseType = "blob";
  oReq.onload = function() {
    var blob = oReq.response;
    excelIO.open(blob, LoadSpread, function(message) {
      console.log(message);
    });
  };
  oReq.send(null);
}

function chkPrtNum(event) {
  var fileName = FILE_NAME;
  excelExport(fileName);
}
```

Comment: It is not possible using native JS, though you can use HTML5 File API and some other hacks but those are not recommended coz it does not support all browsers and it is bad practice to access the file system directly from the client. You should always try to use a server (ex: NodeJs) to access the file system.

Comment: If i want to use the excel file as a database, and i would love to check redundancy btw input value and excel data, then how can i check the redundancy normally?

Comment: Try creating a small server for the same, you will easily get your job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a small server for the same, you will easily get your job done. – Raghu Chahar Jan 28 at 9:50

This was very helpful